# Как узнать значение ключа @Id таблицы Entity до сохранения?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, uuid

Нужно сохранить большое количество связанных таблиц. И нужно знать значение ключа до сохранения в базу.

Подумал, что можно установить `id` в виде `uuid` в конструкторе.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "dsft_depinfo", schema = "public")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    public class DsftDepInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    
    // другие поля

    public DsftDepInfo(...) {
        this.id = Generators.timeBasedGenerator().generate();
        // ...
    }

    }
```

И при создании таблицы использовать скрипт:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name 
(
  pkey UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1() , 
  CONSTRAINT pkey_ table_name PRIMARY KEY ( pkey )
)
```

таким образом у меня будет `id` до сохранения в базу. на сколько этот путь безопасен и верен при сохранении больших значений (около 10 млн записей)? Или может есть другой более изящный путь?

Comment: `нужно знать значение ключа до сохранения в базу.` - самый главный вопрос: а зачем обязательно знать до, если это будет пакетное сохранение? Почему не отдать это на откуп Hibernate, используя для этих связанных таблиц отношения @OneToMany и аналогичные? Тогда хибер сам сохранит вложенные сущности, оперируя самостоятельно полученным им первичным ключем родителя

Comment: а  у меня используется пакетное сохранение JDBC без Hibernate. идет сохранение порядка 25 млн строк. и я думаю что проставление ключей увеличит время.

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно сделать, я думаю этот [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742826/how-do-i-know-the-id-before-saving-an-object-in-jpa) вам поможет разобраться.

Если коротко, то вы создаете свой собственный sequense_generator и прописываете кастомную стратегию в аннотации над своим id.